# Issue printing the 2D array index in Java, print statement returns 0 everytime instead of index for both row & column and also does not increase

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

For example:

**OUTPUT that I want:**

```
Enter Row 0 & Column 0 value
```

OR

```
Enter Row & Column value 00
```

**CODE**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] num = new int[2][2];
        int row = 0, column = 0, numbering = 0;
        for (row = 0; row < num.length; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < num.length; column++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Row & Column value " + num[row][column]);
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                num[row][column] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("The Values at " + ++numbering + " Row & column is: " + num[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CODE OUTPUT**

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: System.out.println("Enter Row & Column value " + row + column);

Comment: Thank You very much for the guidance, Just reviewing Java as I left learning it back in 2018.

Works perfectly!

Comment: no images of plain text, please

Comment: @kleopatra what do you mean ? The image is of IntelliJ Output of my code using the print function to adobe PDF

Comment: it's plain text .. so you could c&p it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code in your question, i.e. from the first `for` loop:

```java
System.out.println("Enter Row & Column value " + num[row][column]);
```

You are printing the value of the array element rather than the indexes. Note that in Java the elements of an `int` array are implicitly initialized to 0 (zero). Hence the prompt that your code prints for the user to enter a value always displays zero, e.g.

```
Enter Row & Column value 0
```

I suggest using method [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) rather than method `println` as follows:

```java
System.out.printf("Enter Row & Column value %d,%d%n", row, column);
```

In the second `for` loop you want to print both the indexes and the value of the array element at those indexes. Again, I suggest using method `printf`.

```java
System.out.printf("The Values at Row %d & column %d is: %d%n", i, j, num[i][j]);
```

This means that you do not require local variable `numbering`.

Also, you should create the `Scanner` before the first `for` loop because you only need to create a `Scanner` object once and not in every loop iteration.

Here is my rewrite of your code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] num = new int[2][2];
        int row = 0, column = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (row = 0; row < num.length; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < num[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.printf("Enter Row & Column value %d,%d%n", row, column);
                num[row][column] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("The Values at Row %d & column %d is: %d%n", i, j, num[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in Java an array may be [jagged](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jagged-array-in-java/). Hence this code gives the number of elements in a given row of the 2D array:

```java
num[row].length
```

Sample run:

```
Enter Row & Column value 0,0
11
Enter Row & Column value 0,1
22
Enter Row & Column value 1,0
33
Enter Row & Column value 1,1
44
The Values at Row 0 & column 0 is: 11
The Values at Row 0 & column 1 is: 22
The Values at Row 1 & column 0 is: 33
The Values at Row 1 & column 1 is: 44
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print the value at the current row and column index of the 2D array, but the array has not been initialized yet so it will print 0. On this line

```
System.out.println("Enter Row & Column value " + num[row][column]);
```

Try using something like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter Row " + row + " & Column " + column + " value ");
```